# How can I have one submit button for multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I have tried to make one submit button submit multiple forms using the following resources:

- https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/255723/two-forms-one-submit-button-hw-does-it-work
- https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/post-multiple-forms-with-a-single-button-press-with-javascript.2271691/
- http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10351103-submit-two-forms-with-one-button

When I use any of code from above, I can submit only one of my forms and its always the last one in the list of all form. I believe the problem could be that every form I have is in separate php file and I'm using `include 'php/option-type.php' ;` to include them in index.php where I also tested codes from above forum.

Comment: Why do you need to use multiple forms? It would be better to determine in the target php script to include one script and process the form than using multiple forms with different targets.

Comment: The problem most likely is the `TARGET` (like `_TOP` or `_BLANK`) and `METHOD` (`GET` vs `POST`) of the forms. One of the solutions might be using AJAX, another to create a hidden form on the fly, etc. It depends on what you are trying to achieve exactly, for that we need to see more code.

Comment: I have in target / index php the scrip which should process multiple forms from different targets.

Comment: @GitaarLAB that sounds interesting. Tomorrow I will test it and inform  all u here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine both forms into one form, and then process the submitted data in a php script, which can then do both actions needed.

Can you give a little more information about the two forms, and what is each `submit` supposed to do? Then I'll be able to elaborate on my answer.